# Understanding the training phase of the tutorial "Using Keras and Deep Deterministic Policy Gradient to play TORCS" tutorial

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, training

I am trying to understand the training phase of the tutorial [Using Keras and Deep Deterministic Policy Gradient to play TORCS](https://yanpanlau.github.io/2016/10/11/Torcs-Keras.html) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20161213122738/https://yanpanlau.github.io/2016/10/11/Torcs-Keras.html), [code](https://github.com/yanpanlau/DDPG-Keras-Torcs)) by Ben Lau published on October 11, 2016.

The tutorial says:

> Then the actor policy is updated using the sampled policy gradient:
>   $$\nabla_\theta J = \frac{\partial Q^{\theta}(s,a)}{\partial a}\frac{\partial \mu(s|\theta)}{\partial \theta}$$

which in the code corresponds to: `actor.train(states, grads)`.

In the [`actor.train()`](https://github.com/yanpanlau/DDPG-Keras-Torcs/blob/572b92cff2e3b7be3b84e92f83a65c06c6fbad1a/ActorNetwork.py#L33) method, I fail to see where $\frac{\partial Q^{\theta}(s,a)}{\partial a}$ gets multiplied by $\frac{\partial \mu(s|\theta)}{\partial \theta}$.

I did [read](https://github.com/yanpanlau/DDPG-Keras-Torcs/blob/572b92cff2e3b7be3b84e92f83a65c06c6fbad1a/ActorNetwork.py#L28):

```
self.params_grad = tf.gradients(self.model.output, self.weights, -self.action_gradient)
```

where `self.action_gradient` corresponds to $\frac{\partial Q^{\theta}(s,a)}{\partial a}$, and `tf.gradients(self.model.output, self.weights)` corresponds to $\frac{\partial \mu(s|\theta)}{\partial \theta}$, but I see no  multiplication.

Where does $\frac{\partial Q^{\theta}(s,a)}{\partial a}$ get multiplied by $\frac{\partial \mu(s|\theta)}{\partial \theta}$?

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [documentation of `tf.gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients) and you will see that the third parameter is used to weight the gradient calculation of first param wrt to second param. This is phrased in the documentation as

> A user can provide their own initial grad_ys to compute the derivatives using a different initial gradient for each y (e.g., if one wanted to weight the gradient differently for each value in each y).

So it essentially uses the `grad_ys` parameter as an element-wise multiplication.

The parameter update gradient calculation in the project code is feeding in the already-calculated value of $\frac{\partial \mu(s|\theta)}{\partial \theta}$ as a placeholder, and using it for this third param.

So the multiplication of the two gradient factors occurs *within* `tf.gradients`.